# Difference between or and || when setting variables

Tags: ruby

I was under the impression that `||` and `or` were synonymous.

Setting variable with `or` does not hold value; why?

```
>> test = nil or true
=> true
>> test
=> nil

>> test = false or true
=> true
>> test
=> false
```

Works 'as expected' with `||`

```
>> test = nil || true
=> true
>> test
=> true
```

Comment: This used to be a gotcha for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`or` has lower *precedence* than `=`.

```
test = nil or true
```

is the same as

```
(test = nil) or true
```

which is `true`, while setting `test` to `nil`.

`||` has higher precedence than `=`.

```
test = nil || true
```

is the same as

```
test = (nil || true)
```

which is `true`, while setting `test` to `true`.

Comment: ...which is why we wouldn't write a piece of code like this, or if we did, we would always use brackets to make it clear what's going on.

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense.

Comment: Not only does `||` have a very high and `or` a very low precedence, but also `and` and `or` have the *same* precedence, whereas `||` and `&&` have different precedences. In general, in conditional expressions, always use the operator forms, because they have the relative precedences that you actually expect them to have. Use `and` and `or` only for control flow, where you actually *want* the "inside" expressions to bind tighter. Something like `test = blah.get_records or puts 'No records found.'`.

Answer (score 1):

Same between `and` and `&&`. I was once bited by this gotcha, then I realize that although `and` is more readable than `&&`, that does not mean it always more suitable.

```
>> f = true && false
=> false
>> f
=> false
>> f = true and false
=> false
>> f
=> true
>>
```